# Can I use variable for 'if' query in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I had multiple points in which I needed to use the same if statement, could I use a javascript variable:

```
var query = ((val!=='CLOSED')||(val!=='OFF')||(val!=='Off'));
if query {
  //statement true;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it instead of asking Stack?

Comment: @Martin — Since that code doesn't work, presumably they have and are asking if there is some alternative syntax that will do the job.

Comment: why not just cache the condition in a variable and use that instead

Comment: [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely.

```
var query = (val!=='CLOSED' || val!=='OFF' || val!=='Off');

if (query) {
  //statement true;
}
```

---

Note that `(val!=='CLOSED' || val!=='OFF' || val!=='Off')` doesn't really make a lot of sense. It would evaluate to `true` for the string `'OFF'`, for example.

You probably want `!(val == 'CLOSED' || val == 'OFF' || val == 'Off')`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to use the statement in every case as it is within an each() loop and so var is not set yet

Answer (score 2):

You can, but your syntax needs to be correct:

```
var query = ((val!=='CLOSED')||(val!=='OFF')||(val!=='Off'));
if(query) {
  //statement true;
}
```

Notice the parenthesis around `query`

Answer (score 2):

You can use function for that if variable will change.

```
function checkVariable(variable) {
    return ((variable !== 'CLOSED') || (variable !== 'OFF') || (variable !== 'Off'));
}

if (checkVariable(variable)) {}
```

If not, then just assign statement value to variable and use it again.

```
var result = (variable !== 'CLOSED' || variable !== 'OFF' || variable !== 'Off');
if (result) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

You could store the result of performing the tests and reuse that (the `if` statement does require the test to be placed in parentheses though):

```
var result = ((val!=='CLOSED')||(val!=='OFF')||(val!=='Off'));

if (result) {
//statement true;
}
```

… but that wouldn't re-evaluate the statements if `val` was to change. So it is not the same as repeating the tests each time.

You could use a function though.

```
var query = function (val) {
    return ((val!=='CLOSED')||(val!=='OFF')||(val!=='Off'));
}

if (query(some_value)) {
  //statement true;
}
```

Comment: ...but `query` is a boolean in the OP's code? I admit I had that line of thought as well at first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but it will always contain a value evaluated at the time the query variable was created.